# How to install Qualcomm USB Drivers in Unbuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, atheros

I would like tether my mobile device to access the internet as I'm unable to connect Wi-Fi for now...I had previously installed Qualcomm USB Drivers in windows via Exe.file (using a dual boot system)

When I connect my device to the system the USB logo flashes for a second (top right of the screen) and disappears.

Also the device is not reflecting in network settings

thanks in advance

Comment: USB tethering or MPT/PTP does NOT require user installable drivers.

Comment: Yes I know that but the device which am using does not have an USB tethering option

Comment: So, which device is that?

Comment: its a Jio F320B its a basic device specially for Indian markets...it runs on kai OS...but the catch is its a 4G device lol...I edited the APN settings in the device setting and installed QUALCOMM drivers in windows and it works like a charm but the device is not detecting ubuntu

Comment: So 1. That information SHOULD have been in the question from the start (please [edit] accordingly) and 2. It may not work at all in desktop Linux (a cursory google search suggest that by omission).

Answer (score 1):

This answer **applies to mobile devices running Android**:

Usually you don't need any "special" USB drivers for most android devices connected to a recent desktop linux installation.

Drivers installed in windows generally are not used when you boot Linux.

Just try the following:

- Connect your android device via USB to the machine running Ubuntu
- when your android notifies you that it is charging your device, choose how to use the current USB connection: (*) USB-Tethering
  **Edit**: if you don't see a tethering option carefully search throug your phone's notifications about "charging from USB" and try to "unfold" this message
- done this your Ubuntu's network-manager will detect a new ethernet (over-USB) device plugged in. Just use it connecting (if not already connected automatically): open network manager "wired settings" and scroll down until you found an ethernet device related to your phone (mine had been labelled "*(phone's brand)* Ethernet") and use it like a plugged-in ethernet connection.

Note: the mobile phone will just behave like an ethernet over usb device and provide DHCP as your home router would do when connecting via ethernet cable.

Note2: order is important

- first connect the phone to the computer via USB (just like you would when charging the phone)
- then "tell" the phone to provide USB Tethering via this connection
- use the provided ethernet via USB from your Ubuntu (if not already connected)

Comment: Yes the step you mention works on Android devices...but this is Kai OS....I edited the APN settings in the device settings and installed QUALCOMM drivers in windows and it works like a charm but the device is not detecting in Ubuntu... here is a link I followed in youtube...its in different language but its pretty understandable  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wQBoBfkPRY&t=240s